# Very quickly sequentially subsetting a large data frame (or data table) on a numeric position column via a large vector of numeric positions

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do this much faster:

```
set.seed(100)
pos     <- sample(1:100000000, 10000000, replace=F)
df      <- data.table(pos, name="arbitrary_string")
query   <- sample(1:100000000, 10000, replace=F)
df_list <- lapply(query, function(x) subset(df, pos >= x - 10000 & pos <= x + 10000))
output  <- rbindlist(df_list)
```

So basically, I'm looping through a vector of positions X and extracting every row from a data frame that has a number in the "pos" column that falls between a range defined as  [X - 10000, X + 10000]. I expect some rows will to be represented multiple times in "output"; this is desirable. The ordering doesn't need to be the same as returned by the code posted in this question.

This toy example is based on a much larger set of data that I estimate will take ~10,000 hours to run on a single core as programmed above. It is therefore valuable to me to have a radically faster solution to this problem. I'd like a pure R solution, but I'm open to solutions that involve other languages.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, I'm going to assume the row ordering doesn't matter (unfortunately it won't work if you need the exact row ordering you have in your original post). The approach I propose is:

1. Determine the number of times you need elements from each range within the pos variable using `cumsum`.
2. Determine the range each element of `df$pos` falls into using a single call to the `cut` function.
3. Grab each row the appropriate number of times, subsetting `df` only once.

This approach cuts down on the number of times you scan `df` and grab a subset, which should yield a significant speedup. Let's start with a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(144)
pos <- sample(1:100000000, 10000000, replace=F)
df <- data.table(pos, name="arbitrary_string")
query <- c(100000, 101000, 200000)
```

Now, let's determine the ranges and number of times we need rows from each range:

```
query.cut <- rbind(data.frame(x=query-10000, y=1), data.frame(x=query+10001, y=-1))
query.cut <- query.cut[order(query.cut$x),]
query.cut$y <- cumsum(query.cut$y)
query.cut
#        x y
# 1  90000 1
# 2  91000 2
# 4 110001 1
# 5 111001 0
# 3 190000 1
# 6 210001 0
```

We will take rows with `pos` value 90000-90999 once, rows with `pos` value 91000-110000 twice, rows with `pos` value 110001-111000 once, and rows with `pos` value 190000-210000 once.

To determine which range an element falls in, we can use the `cut` function, looking up the relevant number of replications in our `query.cut` table:

```
num.rep <- query.cut$y[as.numeric(cut(df$pos, query.cut$x))]
num.rep[is.na(num.rep)] <- 0
table(num.rep)
# num.rep
#       0       1       2 
# 9995969    2137    1894
```

For our current small query, almost all rows are never taken at all. The last step is to grab each row the appropriate number of times.

```
output <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), times=num.rep),]
```

We can get a pretty solid speedup even with a relatively small set of queries (300 here):

```
OP <- function(query) {
  df_list <- lapply(query, function(x) subset(df, pos >= x - 10000 & pos <= x + 10000))
  rbindlist(df_list)
}    
josilber <- function(query) {
  query.cut <- rbind(data.frame(x=query-10000, y=1), data.frame(x=query+10001, y=-1))
  query.cut <- query.cut[order(query.cut$x),]
  query.cut$y <- cumsum(query.cut$y)
  query.cut <- query.cut[!duplicated(query.cut$x, fromLast=T),]
  num.rep <- query.cut$y[as.numeric(cut(df$pos, query.cut$x))]
  num.rep[is.na(num.rep)] <- 0
  df[rep(1:nrow(df), times=num.rep),]
}

set.seed(144)
big.query <- sample(df$pos, 300)
system.time(OP(big.query))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 196.693  17.824 217.141 
system.time(josilber(big.query))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.418   0.124   3.673
```

As the size of query set grows the advantage of the new approach should get larger, because it's still making just one pass through `df$pos` while the original approach is making one pass for each element in `query` (aka the new approach is asymptotically faster).